# iOS - Calling method in distant class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I'm working on an application in which I require to call a function from class `ViewController` when instructed to do so in class `NewNoteController`.

I change between different view controllers this way:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

The problem with this, is that when I switch to ViewController, `(void)viewDidLoad` is not called. What should I use to call a method in `ViewController.m` from `NewNoteController.m`?

Comment: you should never call viewDidLoad directly, it is called by the system after self.view has been instantiated. You need to figure out why viewDidLoad isn't happening, not how to call it.

Comment: So, it should be called with the piece of code I use to change my views?

Comment: The `UIViewController` method `viewDidLoad` uses a lowercase v, not uppercase. Is that what you're using?

Comment: I'm sorry. It was just a mistake in this post. In the code it is `viewDidLoad`. I'll edit the post now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below code..

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
ViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[vc yourmethodname];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Thank you. This calls the `viewDidLoad` as I intended to do. I did however have to replace `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];` with `[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];` because the views didn't change.

Comment: Move the code useful to you in viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method..While presentview it will call viewWillAppear not viewDidLoad.